# Using DATE_SUB() based off dynamic field

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

How does one go abouts using a dynamically created field to be used within a DATE_SUB calculation?

I have this SQL below:

```
SELECT *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN `currentDate` IS NULL 
            THEN 
                `lastDate`
            ELSE 
                `currentDate`
        END AS `useDate`, 
        CASE 
            WHEN `type` = 'weekly' 
                THEN DATE_SUB(`useDate`, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
            END AS `nextDate`
    FROM `aTable`
```

And this does not work, due to error '#1054 - Unknown column 'useDate' in 'field list''

The query works fine if I am using an actual field from the Select *, however won't accept the dynamically created field.

What would the proper way to work with this without having to do a 'case in case' query?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `CASE` clause inside `WHEN`?

```
SELECT *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN `currentDate` IS NULL 
            THEN `lastDate`
            ELSE `currentDate`
        END AS `useDate`, 
        CASE 
            WHEN `type` = 'weekly' 
                THEN DATE_SUB(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN `currentDate` IS NULL 
                            THEN `lastDate`
                            ELSE `currentDate` 
                        END AS `useDate`
                    , INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
            END AS `nextDate`
    FROM `aTable`
```

Comment: That is one way I thought of doing it, but it just seems messy (considering there will be multiple `type`'s) and potentially doubling up on code that doesn't need to be there

Comment: Oh I see. You asked a workaround, so I gave you a workaround. IMO you should have put some info that 'you don't want to use case-when anymore in where'. Yes, that is messy. How about subquery, a view or temp-table ?

Comment: Sorry about that, a subquery would probably be my next attempt; just wanted to know if there was a neat way to do this though :(